# Can anyone explain Chrome delay after initial html request?

Tags: asp.net, performance, google-chrome

Sporadically (but much more frequently than desired), our web app seems to produce Google Chrome delays - and has done so for a long time. Please see this Chrome network graph; and notice the large time-gap after the first request:

[image: Chrome network graph]

Sometimes the page load is as fast as can be, so I don't believe there's an issue with our html. Also, other browsers do not exhibit these sporadic delays.

Note that I always run the latest version of Chrome. Our site is ASP.NET 4.5. All pages are SSL.

Comment: Do you have this live for check it out ?

Comment: Thanks Aristos - I'm afraid it's not public-facing. I have learned about chrome://net-internals/, and am trying to see if this can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, we believe the issue is documented (and resolved) here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155270

We have downloaded version 24-beta of Chrome, and no longer see the issue.